# Logarithms and ratios.

Tags: logarithms, lambert-w

This is the question: $$\log_b 64 = \frac{3}{b}$$

And have to find $b$.

So I tried a bit and got this:$$\frac{b}{\log b} = \frac{\log 64}{3}$$

But have no idea what to do next.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It means $b^{3/b}=64$ or $b^{1/b}=4$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant yup i was wondering how to get that , thx for the help :)

Comment: $b=-1/2$ satisfies this.  Not sure if that's the only solution.

Comment: @GregoryGrant my book says b = 4

Comment: $\log_4 64 = 3 \not = \dfrac34$

Comment: @MohitBhasi, $b=4$ would be correct if the equation were $\log_464=3$ instead of $3/b$.  Are you sure that's not what your book says?

Comment: $b=-1/2$ satisfies $b^{1/b}=4$ but I don't think you should use a negative number as the base of a logarithm.

Comment: @GregoryGrant, I'll second that.  If the OP's book has $3/b$ on the right hand side, it's probably a typo.

Comment: The OP is 16 so probably in 10th grade, so this is probably Algebra II.  So it might be a fair question at that level.  But if the back of the book says the answer is 4 then obviously something is awry.

Comment: @GregoryGrant got it ! the answer is actually four , will post my answer

Comment: It must be a typo. The solution of the equation is a complex number.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici nope !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici i dont know how to write the eqns so its taking time

Answer (score 1):

$$\log _b 4^{3} = 3 \log _b 4  = \frac{3}{b} \implies  \log _b 4  = \frac{1}{b} \implies b^{\frac{1}{b}} = 4$$

**Edit:**

$$\begin{align} b = 4 ^b \implies \ln b = b \ln 4 &\implies b = e^{b \ln 4} \implies be^{-b\ln 4} = 1 \\&\implies -b\ln 4 e^{-b\ln 4} = -\ln 4 \implies b = \color{red}{-\frac{W (-\ln 4)}{\ln 4 }} \end{align}$$

where $W$ is the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: And so $b=-\frac12$

Comment: No $b=4$ does not satisfy it.  The LHS would be 3 since $4^3=64$ and that does not equal $3/4$.

Comment: Where is the answer ? Moreover, it got an upvote !! Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici posted my answer but its not well formatted . can you pls help?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici My net was broken and I couldn't finish it.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone can edit this for me , it would be helpful :)

$$\log _b 4^{3} = 3 \log _b 4  = \frac{3}{b} \implies  \log _b 4  = \frac{1}{b}$$

So:

$$\frac{\log b}{b} = \log 4$$

Using equation:

if log to base b (n) = x

then b^x = n

hence we can say:

$b = 10^{\log 4}$

$b = 4$

NOTE: All the log with no base mentioned has a base 10

Comment: Notice that this can't be right since $\frac{\log 4}{4}\not=\log 4$

Comment: Everything up to the "Therefore" is OK, but everything after is wrong.  $b=4$ is *not* a solution to ${\log b\over b}=\log4$, no matter what base the log has.  I still think there was a typo in the problem, and the equation to solve should have just been $\log_b64=3$.

Comment: @BarryCipra there is a formula

Comment: @MohitBhasi, I'm not sure what you mean by that.  Books do sometimes have typos in them.

Comment: @BarryCipra edited my answer , check it out

Comment: $b=10^{\frac{\log(4)}{\log(b)}}$

Comment: @MohitBhasi, your solution is still wrong.  From ${\log b\over b}=\log4$ you can get to $\log b=b\log4=\log4^b$, which you can turn into $b=4^b$, not $b=4$.  I'll say again, the answer to the problem **as stated** is **not** $b=4$, and I'm guessing there is simply a typo in the book.